# "Саммит" - есть ли замена слову?

Tags: иностранные-слова

"Саммит" - каким родным словом можно заменить? Непонятно, зачем его ввели в обиход телевизионщики.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Помнится, в советских газетах это называлось по-русски и вполне понятно: "встреча на высшем уровне"

Comment: Хорошо, но немного длинно. А мы ведь все сегодня торопимся ((

Answer (score 1):

"Встреча на высшем уровне" - не совсем здесь подходит. Это скорее tet-a-tet между двумя  главами, редко - тремя-четырьмя. 
А "саммит" - это когда их много, руководителей, хороших и разных, и все сразу. В русском такие вещи называются слетами, съездами, но с "высшим уровнем" съезд или слет как-то не очень согласуется.

Не вижу причин бороться с "саммитом". В английском это слово тоже появилось совсем недавно, вместе с понятием (вроде бы от французского "sommet" - "верхушка"), и никто поиском "исконно английского" слова не озаботился. Почему бы не принять его и в русском?

Comment: Често признаюсь, у меня проблемы с иностранными языками. Слова не запоминаю совершенно. Поэтому тяжело. 

"Переговоры АТЭС". Просто и доступно.
И вообще, можно было и своё слово придумать, зачем всё заимствовать.

Answer (score 1):

Великолепный вопрос: ЗАЧЕМ всякое иностранное словестный мусор вводят в русский обиход телевизионщики! Сначала отвечу Бегемотам и другим остальным любителям американизмов. "Саммит" - это никакая не групповуха. Саммит - это буквально "встреча на высшем уровне". Независимо от количества - хоть два главы государства. "Summit" - английское слово, самостоятельное от французского "sommet", котрое означает то же самое - "вершина", "верхушка". Именно американцы, а не французы ввели это слово, а французы, к их чести, как обычно, подобрали своё французское, а не стали копировать, как мы, американское. И мы, если бы у нас был тот же уровень национального самоуважения, что и в советский и дореволюционный период, придумали бы своё слово в значении "вершина". Как вариант, "верховная встреча", "верховка" и т.п. А вот ЗАЧЕМ - это ВОПРОС современного уничтожения русского языка. Потому что сейчас монополия на формирование русского языка не у писателей, не у народа, не у села, как это было раньше, а у рекламщиков и СМИ. Им ВЫГОДНО для привлечения внимания давать слова-блестяшки, самые простые из которых и совершенно интеллектуально незатратные - это тупо заимствованные американизмы.

Answer (score 0):

Саммит - встреча, переговоры глав государств, правительств.